# saving view in Mysql

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, view

I have a Mysql query from which I am printing output.  I want to save this query as a view so I can print aggregated output from the view.  In this very simplified example I create the view, then run two queries against it.  Everything is working fine.  However, it seems like I have gone to the database 3 times -- once for the view and twice for the queries.  It is possible to go only twice to the database by doing the first query, REQUESTING THAT BE TURNED INTO A VIEW, and then doing the second query.  I am in Cold Fusion and tried Query of Queries, but it is too limited to do even the simple example below.

```
<cfquery name = "viewtest" datasource = "Moxart">

alter view testview AS
select PersonFn, PersonLn, PersonState, dec1 from Person
where PersonState = <cfqueryparam value = "PA">
OR PersonState =  <cfqueryparam value = "NJ">
order by PersonState,PersonLN
</cfquery>

<cfquery name = "test" datasource = "Moxart">
select * from testview
</cfquery>

<table>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array = #test.getColumnList()# index = "col">
<td>#col#</td>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput query = "test">
<tr>
<cfloop array = #test.getColumnList()# index = "col">
<td>#test[col][currentrow]#</td>
</cfloop>
</tr>
</cfoutput>

</table>

<cfset j = 0>
<cfloop array = #test.getColumnList()# index = "scol">  
<cfset j = j + 1>
   <cfif j EQ 1>
   <cfset aggcnt = "count(#scol#)"> 
   </cfif>   
<cfset aggarr[j] ="sum(#scol#)">             
</cfloop>

<cfset aggls = ArrayToList(aggarr)>

<cfoutput>
<cfquery name = "vtest" datasource = "Moxart">
select #aggls#, #aggcnt# from testview
group by PersonState
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>

<table>
<tr>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array = #vtest.getColumnList()# index = "col">
<td>#col#</td>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput query = "vtest">
<tr>
<cfloop array = #vtest.getColumnList()# index = "col">
<td>#vtest[col][currentrow]#</td>
</cfloop>
</tr>

</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: (Edit) Your question is not very clear. Creating a `view` is generally a one time event, not per request. So it is unclear why the number of database calls would be a concern. Forget about the `view` for a minute (not sure you even need one). Maybe back up a bit and explain the goal in plain english first. What does your table store, and what results are you trying to pull from the database? It looks like some sort of counts by state ... ?

Comment: @Leigh, the database contains lots of stuff -- in the real world there are a lot of joins.  I need to pull information which the user chooses (say, Name, Address, State, Amount Paid) and put it in a very highly formatted report. I also need counts and subtotals to be placed at appropriate places in the report, which might be at state breaks, or other breaks.  So far the only way I've found is to make two queries and then hook things together.  Re the view, it will indeed keep changing, so I would expect at most 2 hits on it before it changes.

Comment: (Edit) A permanent `view` is not a good choice for something that volatile, because it is visible to all connections. So you would have concurrency problems/errors if multiple requests tried to alter the `view` at the same time. If you really cannot achieve this with a `select`, then temp tables might be a better choice - because they are per session.

Comment: Also, do not forget about stored procedures. They are specifically designed for situations that require multiple (or complex) sql operations. From what you described, this sounds like a good candidate. You could perform the bulk of the aggregates within a procedure, using a temp table(s) and a few sql statements -  using only a single database connection. Plus, unlike cfquery, stored procedures can return multiple resultsets, not just one.

Comment: Right now I'm using a table, and dropping it before creating a new one.  Once that table is there the 2 subsequent queries are pretty trivial, so if performance is okay I'll do it this way.  I didn't know that there was a designation of temporary, and am considering if that helps.  You're right about possible concurrency problems and I'll arrange to avoid them.  Looked at stored procedures and will not go there right now, but keeping it in mind. You've pointed out to me several things re my various posts which are most helpful; as a beginner with this technology I am grateful.

Comment: Well tables have the same potential for concurrency clashes. (Any *permanent* object will). To avoid it, you must use an object that is only visible to the current connection, like a temp table. At this stage, I would not worry about *one* extra db query. It is not like you are running that query within a loop (which *is* bad for performance). Also, it possible you could generate the aggregates within the first cfoutput loop, using CF variables, instead of a query. Hard to say if that is the best option, just based on your scaled down example, but it is something to keep in mind.